# Is this haram and shirk?

Tags: sunni, non-muslim, shirk, books, halal-haram

Salam, so this is worrying me a lot and I would really like someone to help me please

Is it shirk to say I won’t be rude about a certain person for another person’s sake to not offend them?

As earlier I was in the shower and was going to perform wudu but before I did I was thinking about a grandmother I don’t really like much and I got the idea to make fun of her mother to her (who had died) I know this is haram and I’d never do it but then I said to myself that I wouldn’t do that as I really like her brother and for his sake as he’d probably get really offended, I then said something like and for Allah’s sake

Can someone please reply to this as soon as possible as it’s worrying me a lot

Thank you very much

Comment: Would you mind to make clear, what exactly you regard as a possible reason of shirk in this post?

Comment: Saying “for someone’s sake” other than Allah

Answer (score 0):

Brother, you should not commit acts like that and you should not do something because you think someone other than the person you are making fun of will be offended. My advice is to repent to Allah straight away as he is the knower of hidden things and the concealer of mistakes.